# Word/phrase for the 'battle cry' in sports game

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Is there a word/phrase for the 'battle cry' from sports game audience? What about the 'shout' at the end of the scrum?

Comment: What does your second question mean? Are you asking to find another word for that or is it your choice to answer your own first question?

Comment: The second question is another question. I put them together because maybe one word can answer both. To clarify by 'battle cry' I mean the shout from the crowd to cheer the players.

Comment: One word often used to described stadium cries would be _cheer_, which can be used to describe either the roar of the crowd after a big play, or an organized chant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Where I come from**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_Eagle), it's still called a [***battle cry***](http://clip.dj/war-eagle-the-history-of-a-tradition-at-auburn-university-download-mp3-mp4-OOHrrpaeGV8#v/Mqz76a7Qap8) (listen at 0.47). The associated musical composition (whose title and first words are the battle cry) is the [***fight song***](http://fightmusic.com/mp3/sec/Auburn__War_Eagle_old.mp3).

We don't have scrums in my part of the world, so I can't help you with that.

Comment: A scrum (short for scrummage) is a method of re-starting play in rugby football. Don't you have rugby or scrum in the rugby? &^)

Comment: @PersianCat In Alabama we play American football, which is (especially if you come from Auburn) less a sport than a sort of secondary religion.

Comment: Ok! I got it! :)

Comment: @StoneyB I am confused. You do play American football, then what do you mean by you don't have scrums?

Comment: NS.X American football does not have scrums. There is a "line of scrimmage", at which each play starts (action is not continuous), but there is no contest there for possession of the ball.

Answer (score -1):

[Battle cry](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/battle+cry) from The Free dictionary means:

> 1. A rallying cry uttered in combat, especially while attacking.
> 2. A slogan used by the proponents of a cause.

I found these:

[Whoop](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/whoop) from The Free Dictionary:

> A.
>
> - A loud cry of exultation or excitement.
> - A shout uttered by a hunter or warrior.
>
> B. A hooting cry, as of a bird.
>
> C. The paroxysmal gasp characteristic of whooping cough.

[Sports cry](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Sports%20Cry&defid=5976416) from Urban Dictionary:

> The Permissible act of a sports fan or athlete, usually a male, shedding a quiet tear in celebration of their team's accomplishments. Also acceptable at the end of a classic sports motion picture. Only one episode of sports crying is acceptable per situation.
>
> I sports cry every time at the end of 'Angels in the Outfield'.

Comment: I think what OP has in mind is *cry* in the sense "shout" (which is its meaning in *battle cry*) rather than "weep".